# Number of distinct discrete eigenvalues of a self adjoint operator after compact perturbation increases.

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, spectral-theory, perturbation-theory

Let $T$ be a self adjoint operator on a complex separable Hilbert space $H$. Let $K$ be self adjoint compact operator. So, $T+K$ is also self adjoint operator. I want to know for what $K$ the number of distinct discrete eigenvalues of $T+K$ increases.

Is there any theory for the above question?

Thanks

Comment: $T+K$ will in general not be compact. Take $T$
 to be non compact. Then If $T+K$ was compact so would be $T=T+K−K$
, because the compact operators form a vector space. A general compact self adjoint operator can have countably many distinct eigenvalues so i do not understand what you mean by the notion of "the number of distinct discrete eigenvalues" and the notion of the number "increasing"?

Comment: Yes, it was an error in the statement. I want to say $T+K$ is self-adjoint. But it may happen that for a compact self-adjoint operator $K$, $T+K$ has one or two discrete eigenvalues. I am asking that is there any condition on choosing $K$ of having more than two discrete eigenvalues  (distinct) of $T+K$.